# Iterating output into excel

Tags: python

I would like to iterate this information, but break it down by department,  category group, category and sub-category, and then export this information to excel using Python.

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52b6Y.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about pandas dataframe. Read from Excel using pandas, process the pandas dataframe for the required operations, then  write to excel.
https://pythonbasics.org/pandas-dataframe/

[https://pythonbasics.org/read-excel/#:~:text=To%20read%20an%20excel%20file,is%20a%20tabular%20like%20structure](https://pythonbasics.org/read-excel/#:%7E:text=To%20read%20an%20excel%20file,is%20a%20tabular%20like%20structure).